# One data card visual doesn't display latest item but other two data cards do

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

A Power BI report has three card visuals, two of which display the latest item but the other doesn't. They're all from the same data and I can't understand why this particular column isn't being displayed correctly. All of the three cards display text and not numbers and they're all alongside a date column.

I've filtered the raw data into a dummy table to check and the rows display the latest data.

Comment: can you please provide a screenshot or sample data?